# R- making a figure from multiple vectors of different lengths

Tags: r

I have 8 vectors all with different lengths (ranging from 5 to 110) I would like to display box plots for each vector on the same figure but am running into all sorts of issues- are there any packages that make this easier? If anyone can lead me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated! Bonus points if there's an answer using ggplot2!

Comment: Please share a reproducible piece of your data so that others can help you more efficiently.

Comment: Questions on SO in the [tag:r] tag tend to do better when they have sample data. We don't need all eight vectors, we don't need them to be 110 long ... 3-4 vectors with short lengths should suffice. My guess is that `rbind`'ing the data together and using `ggplot2::facet_wrap` will give a combined look you want.

Answer (score 1):

Sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
### these are your data vectors
vec1 <- rnorm(20) ; vec2 <- rexp(30, 3) ; vec3 <- rnorm(40, 3, 5)
```

Combine them into one "long" frame:

```r
### create a "long" frame
dat <- dplyr::bind_rows(A = data.frame(val = vec1), B = data.frame(val = vec2), C = data.frame(val = vec3), .id = "id")
head(dat)
#   id        val
# 1  A  1.3709584
# 2  A -0.5646982
# 3  A  0.3631284
# 4  A  0.6328626
# 5  A  0.4042683
# 6  A -0.1061245
```

The plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(id, val)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]